# How to add new water bounds to OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

[Penikkajarvi](https://www.google.lt/maps/place/65%C2%B046'06.6%22N+29%C2%B039'02.9%22E/@65.736665,29.6081269,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d65.7685!4d29.6508) lake is present on Google Maps but is absent / plain field on [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=65.736665%2C29.6081269#map=6/65.740/29.597).

Is the any way (prefer not manual) to add new water body to OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Manual way is not hard at all. Create OSM user account, select your editor, draw the feature and add the tags (natural=water, name=Penikkajarvi). For a new user it is probably easiest to use the iD editor https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID.

Comment: Currently it is plain field on OSM. I wouldn't draw it accurately by hand.

Comment: The iD editor offers satellite images as a background. They are usually accurate enough for digitizing lakes.

Comment: Found it. I would be easy but there are lots of bays and waters with separate names which overlays / touches the lake so bounds are unclear thats why I mentioned not manual way.

Comment: You can start with a rough lake outline and improve it with subsequent edits. It doesn't have to be perfect right away.

Comment: @user30184 you can post your comments as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create OSM user account and digitize the missing lake yourself. There are a few different editors to select from but iD editor https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID is probably the easiest for a beginner. The link to start editing is https://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?editor=id#map=14/65.7712/29.6541 and as you will see there are rather good satellite images from Bing to use as a background.

The lake is actually already digitized 12 hours ago from now https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/550399779#map=14/65.7705/29.6449&layers=D and it is on the OSM map https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/65.7641/29.6515. It may take some time before it appears also on small scales.